# Loading Hive table from Windows machine (Load data local inpath)

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, talend

I am trying to load a Hive table using a file from Windows. But I am getting the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: IllegalArgumentException
java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected scheme-specific part at index 2: C:
```

I am using Talend ETL tool to process the file. Below is the code generated by Talend:

```
String path_tHiveLoad_1 = "file:///C:/employee.txt";
String tablename_tHiveLoad_1 = "test.employee";
java.sql.Statement stmt_tHiveLoad_1 = conn_tHiveLoad_1
                        .createStatement();
String querySQL_tHiveLoad_1 = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '"
                        + path_tHiveLoad_1 + "' OVERWRITE  INTO TABLE "
                        + tablename_tHiveLoad_1 + "";
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your job layout and also the configuration of the Hive component please?

Answer (score -1):

The file needs to be in hdfs. It can't be loaded from the local or remote filesystem.